# What is the right way to create relations between these tables in a SQL database?

Tags: sql, database, database-schema, rdbms

I have three tables: offices, suboffices, and sales. Each office owns several suboffices, both offices and suboffices sell products. How should I design my sales table to store there office or suboffice where this sale was made?

I was thinking about having a compound foreign key made of office_id and suboffice_id (where suboffice_id may be null, in which case a sale was made in office)
Is it the right way to design a database?
I was also thinking about having two sales tables: for offices and suboffices. But in my opinion it makes things a bit harder..

**UPDATE**

Sales can be of different types, so they will need different tables. And there will be one table 'SALES' which will store type of a sale and where it was made

Comment: better to have two sales tables.because for each entry u have to check whether it belongs to office or suboffice.Also i might me be for analytics too...

Comment: @Vishwa, please view an update. It seems that in such situation there will be a need for a compound foreign key this way or another

Comment: It seems to me that all your sub_offices are also offices. Perhaps there is nothing special about a suboffice and it does not need it's own table. If you could put all offices in one table then you would have another solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to go about this, assuming `OFFICE` and `SUBOFFICE` share many of the same attributes is to eliminate the `SUBOFFICE` table and add a `PARENT_OFFICE_ID` column to the `OFFICE` table. Under this design, the distinction between an office and a sub-office would be whether or not `PARENT_OFFICE_ID` is null. Then `SALES` can simply have an `OFFICE_ID` column that can reference either kind of office.

Answer (score 3):

Your sub-offices sound the same as your offices from a properties point of view. Here is a diagram of what your table design could look like by having your Office table include a ParentOffice foreign key.

[image]

And here is the SQL to create those tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Office](
    [OfficeId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ParentOfficeId] [int] NULL,
    [MoreStuff] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Office] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [OfficeId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Office]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Office_Office] FOREIGN KEY([ParentOfficeId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Office] ([OfficeId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Office] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Office_Office]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Product](
    [ProductId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [MoreStuff] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Product] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ProductId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sale](
    [SaleId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProducitId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [OfficeId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Sale] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SaleId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Sale]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Sale_Office] FOREIGN KEY([OfficeId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Office] ([OfficeId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Sale] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Sale_Office]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Sale]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Sale_Sale] FOREIGN KEY([ProducitId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Product] ([ProductId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Sale] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Sale_Sale]
GO
```